# Clarification regarding pads in Maxpool

Tags: onnx, max-pooling

I need clarification on pads in Maxpool. In the example [here](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/Operators.md#MaxPool) (maxpool_2d_pads) pads are mentioned as pad_bottom , pad_top , pad_right , pad_left, and in the attached screenshot pads are (0,0,1,1). Are the pads mentioned in the format (pad_bottom , pad_top , pad_right , pad_left)? If not, what is the right interpretation?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of the pads for MaxPool [here](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/Operators.md#MaxPool)

> ***pads : list of ints*** ... `pads` format should be as follow [x1_begin, x2_begin...x1_end, x2_end,...], where xi_begin the number of pixels added at the beginning of axis `i` and xi_end, the number of pixels added at the end of axis `i`. ...

So for your example, the pads are in the format `[pad_top, pad_left, pad_bottom, pad_right]`

This following part is copied from the answer from [user2008981](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008981/user2008981) below,

The pads are in order of the spatial axes of the X input. The X input has dimensions N x C x H x W when rank 4 (per the docs). So the spatial dimensions are x1=H (vertical) then x2=W (horizontal). Horizontal goes left to right, vertical goes top to bottom. x1_begin=top, x2_begin=left, x1_end=bottom, x2_end=right.

Comment: Can you explain little more on how did you derive that?

Comment: The pads are in order of the spatial axes of the X input. The X input has dimensions `N x C x H x W` when rank 4 (per the docs).  So the spatial dimensions are x1=H (vertical) then x2=W (horizontal).  Horizontal goes left to right, vertical goes top to bottom.  x1_begin=top, x2_begin=left, x1_end=bottom, x2_end=right.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.